# Javascript error - unexpected identifier

Tags: php, javascript

I have PHP code that tries to output JavaScript and I do something like this:

```
trailhead_name = <?php echo $objkey->trailhead_name ?> + "";
```

And I get the unexpected identifier error in my JS.

Comment: Try running your js through jslint.com, it will often give a more specific error.

Comment: Don't show us what you do "something like", show us what you do.

Comment: Don't show us some PHP that generates some JavaScript which throws an error, show us the JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `trailhead_name` is a string, you need to put quotes around it (and properly escape anything within it that may not be a valid JavaScript string — like a quote!).

PHP's built-in [JSON encoder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) can do that for you:

```
trailhead_name = <?php echo json_encode($objkey->trailhead_name) ?>;
```

Again, that assumes that `trailhead_name` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode`:

```
var trailhead_name = <?php echo json_encode($objkey->trailhead_name); ?>;
```